# How to sort multiple FASTA files based on their content?

Tags: python, covid-19, virus

So I have around 10,000 FASTA files of Influenza A virus. These files contains sequences of each of the 8 segments of the viral genome and I want to separate these files into different locations based on the content of these FASTA files.
In each FASTA file, first line has the segment number.
Eg.

```
>KM368312.1 Influenza A virus (A/swine/Shandong/01/2009(H1N1)) segment 3 polymerase PA (PA) and PA-X protein (PA-X) genes, complete cds
```

Okay imagine you have 10,000 text files in one folder and there are 8 types of these text files based on the content of them. Eg. file1.txt has segment 1 written in it, file2.txt has segment 2 written in it upto segment 8. So I want to group the files containing segment 1 together in one folder, segment 2 in other folder together and so on.

Comment: I edited your question to make it more readable. Check if I interpreted it correctly and change if not.

Comment: Thank you, It's my first time using stackoverflow, so sorry about that.

Comment: My genetics knowledge is quite basic. Which is the part you want to sort by? (I assume you have several folders with that name where the corresponding files should go?)

Comment: We can treat these fasta files as basic text files containing sequences. So i have 10,000 text files and i want to sort them into different folders based on the segment sequence these files have. Eg. One text file will have segment 1 sequence only, and so on.  In total there are 8 segments, so 8 folders.
I hope i am clear now.

Comment: What's the "segment sequence" part? `KM368312.1`?

Comment: This is accession number, but each text file will have a unique accession number.
But i want to group together all the segment 1 files together and so on.

Comment: I won't guess again. What exactly is the wanted part?

Comment: Okay imagine you have 10,000 text files in one folder and there are 8 types of these text files based on the content of them. Eg. file1.txt has segment 1 written in it, file2.txt has segment 2 written in it upto segment 8. So I want to group the files containing segment 1 together in one folder, segment 2 in other folder together and so on.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: why? It's about textfiles and sorting them. That the content of the files happens to be about genetic, doesn't change that (and is completely irrelevant to the question).

Comment: @Stephan There’s naturally overlap between the two sites but there are dedicated tool and libraries for working with FASTA files. But, furthermore, the current question is completely off topic on Stack Overflow because it is a “please write code for me” question. On bioinformatics.SE we’re generally more tolerant of such questions for specific bioinformatics-related tasks.

Comment: The close notice is confusing because each close voter found a different reason to close this - you are vaguely violating several of the guidelines for [What topics can I ask about here.](/help/on-topic) Probably review the [help] and in particular also [How to ask.](/help/how-to-ask) If you can [edit] this into a well-scoped question about a Python program you have written, with details about what you have already tried and how it failed, it can certainly be salvaged and reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite easy with `cmd`:

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,8) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%f in ('findstr  /mc:" segment %%i " *.txt') do (
    ECHO move "%%f" "segment %%i\"
  )
)
```

`findstr /mc:"string" *.txt` searches each matching file for the string and outputs the filename, if the string was found. The `for /f` loop around catches those filenames, so you are able to move them. The `for /l` loop just iterates from 1 to 8.

See `for /?` and `findstr /?` for more information about those commands.

You probably want to adapt the filemask `*.txt` to your needs.

Note: I "disarmed" the `move` command for troubleshooting. Remove the `ECHO` when you are sure it does what you want.

Comment: I know this is tagged `cmd` but it’s very unlikely that OP is actually using Windows when working with FASTA files.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is:

1. iterate over all files

   1. read the first line of each file, extract the `segment` bit
   2. move the file based on that

In Python, this can be done in many ways. Here’s one way:

```py
import os
import re


def find_segment(id):
    return re.search(r'segment (\d)', id).group(1)


for segment in range(8):
    os.mkdir(f'segment-{segment + 1}')

for entry in os.scandir():
    if not entry.is_file():
        continue

    with open(entry.path, 'r') as file:
        segment = find_segment(next(file))
    os.rename(entry.path, f'segment-{segment}/{entry.path}')
```

Note the absence of error handling — this code assumes that every operation succeeds; empty files, or files without “`segment X`” in their FASTA ID, will trigger an error, as will usual IO failures (missing permissions, etc.).

---

But many people wouldn’t use Python to solve this but a shell scripting language. For example, here’s something equivalent in Bash (untested):

```sh
mkdir segment-{1..8}

for file in *.fa *.fasta; do
    segment=$(sed 's/.*segment \([[:digit:]]\).*/\1/; q' "$file")
    if [[ "$segment" != '' ]]; then
        mv "$file" "segment-$segment"
    done
done
```